# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.reduce)

Tags: react-native

Here my codes :

```
Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStart.bind(this);
Voice.onSpeechRecognized = this.onSpeechRecognized.bind(this);
Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults.bind(this);}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);}

  onSpeechStart(e) {
    this.setState({
      started: "√"}
);}

  onSpeechRecognized(e) {
    this.setState({
      recognized: "√"
    });
  }

  onSpeechResults(e) {
   this.setState({results: e.value});

   if(matchSorter(this.setState.results,'login now') === 'login now'){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
   }
   else {
        ToastAndroid.show("Please Try Again", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
   }
  }

async _startRecognition(e) {
this.setState({
  recognized: "",
  started: "",
  results: []
});
try {
  await Voice.start("en-US");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}


 render() {
    return (
    <Text>Say "Login now"</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this._startRecognition.bind(this)}>
    <Text> TAP HERE </Text>}
```

and this error coming out :

Error Image from Android-based Mobile:

[image]

*The output of "**this.setState.results**" when I say login now is "**blogging nowlogging nowlogin nowjogging nowlog in now**".

Comment: The code you posted is not sufficient for SO users to resolve your problem. Please edit your post so as to include relevant part of your code (ie, the ones where the error happen)

Comment: Looks like this is incorrect: `(matchSorter(this.setState.results,'login now')` - change `this.setState.results` to `this.state.results`

Comment: I have add some part of the code. The error happen at "onSpeechResults(e)". Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @DacreDenny, thank for your reply. I had change the this.setState.results to this.state.results.  The error gone but   the page doesn't navigate to the Dashboard, it still stay at the LoginPage. (Sorry for any grammer mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried to retrive value from state then you have to write code like : **this.state.VARIBLENAME**. You have this.setState.VARIBLENAME which is wrong.

Correction from your code:

```
   if(matchSorter(this.state.results,'login now') === 'login now'){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
   }
```

Your whole code:

```
Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStart.bind(this);
Voice.onSpeechRecognized = this.onSpeechRecognized.bind(this);
Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults.bind(this);}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);}

  onSpeechStart(e) {
    this.setState({
      started: "√"}
);}

  onSpeechRecognized(e) {
    this.setState({
      recognized: "√"
    });
  }

  onSpeechResults(e) {
   this.setState({results: e.value});

   if(matchSorter(this.state.results,'login now') === 'login now'){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
   }
   else {
        ToastAndroid.show("Please Try Again", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
   }
  }

async _startRecognition(e) {
this.setState({
  recognized: "",
  started: "",
  results: []
});
try {
  await Voice.start("en-US");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}


 render() {
    return (
    <Text>Say "Login now"</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this._startRecognition.bind(this)}>
    <Text> TAP HERE </Text>
}
```

You can replace the code and it will work for you.

Comment: Thank for reply. I changed the code but it never navigate to the dashboard. I say "login now" and the output of 
`this.state.result` is `login nowlooking now log in nowlogin nolocking now`.

Comment: @DMCEXC It runs your logic and it will move to login screen.

Comment: I think the question which you asked is resolved from my comment.